# Jquery Shorten text with show more/less with nested elements

Tags: jquery

I am not an expert in jquery and trying to use the following Script to display a show more link when the text is greater than certain number of character.

Here is the working example at jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/enpqqfb4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ ' </span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>  <a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
});
```

But this code breaks when you have nested elements and it display the entire text on page load with show more link below which when clicked hides the entire text. Below if the content which is causing it to break.

```
This is the first line of the content
<ul>
 <li>one item </li> ---- First 50 characters end after text 'one' and </li> and proceeding text goes to next moretext div.
 <li>two item </li>
 <li>three item </li>
 <li>four item </li> 
 <li>five item </li>
<ul>
```

Any suggestion on how can i fix this ?

Comment: Could you create a 'working' example with actual text and post it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/enpqqfb4/

Comment: @SonaliKapoor Can you give the content which breaks the actual behavior?

Comment: I have added the content as well as the javascript in the working example at jsfiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/enpqqfb4

Just incase you still need to see it. here it is 

`<div class="more">
    Duis nisl nibh, egestas at fermentum at, viverra et purus.
    <ul>
        <li>Maecenas lobortis odio id sapien facilisis elementum.</li>
        <li>Curabitur et magna justo, et gravida augue.</li>
        <li> Sed tristique pellentesque arcu quis tempor.</li>
       </ul>  
</div>`

Comment: http://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA/